# LSI 9211-8i won't boot in KVM

Tags: virtualization, sas, lsi, kvm-virtualization

I'm running ubuntu 11.04 with an LSI 9211-8i in IT mode with the latest firmware (10). I'm using KVM with VT-d enabled to pass the entire PCIe device through to the guest OS. I have the device disabled in the system BIOS.

When I boot my virtual machine, the adapter quits during bios initialization with the following error:

```
Unable to load LSI Corporation MPT BIOS
MPT BIOS Fault 0Ch encountered at adapter PCI(00h,04h,00h)
Press any key to continue...
```

I know the virtualization is correctly enabled. I've blacklisted the kernel modules in the host OS.

Has anyone else encountered this error? I'm about out of ideas here.

Edit:

I contacted LSI tech support about this, and they suggested that I try RedHat and Xen. Apparently they don't test or support anything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case anybody stumbles upon this: the solution to such a problem is to set `rombar=0` in the PCI passthrough in your `vm.conf`:

```
hostpci0: 06:00.0,rombar=0
```

(whereas `06:00.0` is the relevant slot you want to passthrough)